# Python unittest call function when assertion passes

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions, python-unittest

I can't find a way to do_something() when the assertion in a test passes. For example:

```
    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1, "Did not match")
```

That test will print "Did not match" if the assertion would fail, but in this case it will not, so I'm trying to call a function or print something when the self.assertEqual() is successful, please any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print when something passes, there are a couple of options. However, please don't use [Noeld's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16676604/590904). Not that it is wrong, it's just that you don't want to clutter your test with a bunch of `print` messages when `unittest` provides better ways for doing this.

### Verbosity

If you want to print the result of every single `test_` function, set the verbosity of the test runner. You can do this in a couple of ways:

1. From the command line, use the [verbose](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) option:

   `python -m unittest discover -v`
2. Programmatically calling the `unittest.main` and passing it the
   [verbosity
   argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.main)

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       unittest.main(verbosity=2)
   ```

### Running tests "manually"

1. Programmatically building up your TestSuite and calling the
   TestRunner with the verbosity argument.

   ```
   suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(TestModuleName)
   results = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
   ```
2. Creating a subclass of the [TestResult
   object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult), which contains an [addSuccess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.addSuccess) method which will be called whenever a test passes.

   You can then pass this TestResult object to the [Test Suite's run method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestSuite.run).

   ```
       suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromModule(TestModuleName)
       suite.run(myTestResult)
   ```

### Third party runners

Take a look at [Twisted's Trial](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedTrial).
It contains many different [Test Runners](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.1.0/api/twisted.trial.reporter.html) which might be useful. By default, it runs the `TreeReporter` which looks like:

[image: Trial reporting]

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import unittest


class TestupSomeStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_fail(self):
        x = 2 * 4
        self.assertEqual(x,9,"DID NOT MATCH")
        print "Passed"

    def test_pass(self):
        x = 2 * 4
        self.assertEqual(x,8,"DID NOT MATCH")
        print "Passed"





if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This is because if your assert fails then the test is a fail and you go to the next test, however when the test is a success it carries on and returns None!

For example:

```
import unittest


class TestupSomeStuff(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_fail(self):
        return None
        # This is skipped, so test is win
        x = 2 * 4
        self.assertEqual(x,9,"DID NOT MATCH")
        print "FAIL"

    def test_pass(self):
        x = 2 * 4
        self.assertEqual(x,8,"DID NOT MATCH")
        # Passed gets printed after the dot for passing the previous test.
        print "Passed"
```

Prints:

```
.Passed
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this helps accomplish what the OP wants, there are many different ways of accomplishing the same thing using built-in tools.

Comment: Fair point just wanted to demo a simple way of printing a message with out having to subclass methods to get a different message. Nice answer.

Comment: using print is a bad idea when you use Unittest , it has a habit of mangling stdout and it can often make it unclear when a print statement was actually fired. A better approach is to not rely on stdout but to use pythons logging subsystem.